# JEDI JVCL TJvProgramVersionCheck How to use HTTP

Tags: delphi, jvcl

I'm wondering if someone has an example on how can be used the TJvProgramVersionCheck component performing the check via HTTP.

The example in the JVCL examples dir doesn't show how to use HTTP

thank you

Comment: You need to give detailed error information, saying "it doesn't work" in the comments below is not going to get you anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The demo included in your `$(JVCL)\Examples\JvProgramVersionCheck` folder seems to be able to do so. Edit the properties of the `JVProgramVersionHTTPLocation`, and add the URL to it's `VersionInfoLocation` list (a `TStrings`). You can also set up any username, password, proxy, and port settings if needed.

You also need to add an `OnLoadFileFromRemote` event handler. I don't see anything in the demo that addresses that requirement, but the source code says:

```
{ Simple HTTP location class with no http logic.
The logic must be implemented manually in the OnLoadFileFromRemote event }
```

It appears from the parameters that event receives that you do your checking there:

```
function TJvProgramVersionFTPLocation.LoadFileFromRemoteInt(
  const ARemotePath, ARemoteFileName, ALocalPath, ALocalFileName: string;
  ABaseThread: TJvBaseThread): string;
```

So you'll need to add an event handler for this event, and then change the `TJVProgramVersionCheck.LocationType` property to `pvltHTTP` and run the demo. After testing, it seems you're provided the server and filename for the remote version, and a local path and temp filename for the file you download. The event handler's `Result` should be the full path and filename of the newly downloaded file. Your event handler should take care of the actual retrieval of the file.

There are a couple of additional types defined in `JvProgramVersionCheck.pas`, (`TJvProgramVersionHTTPLocationICS` and `TJvProgramVersionHTTPLocationIndy`, both protected by compiler defines so they don't exist in the default compilation. However, setting the `ICS` related define resulted in lots of compilation errors (it apparently was written against an old version of `ICS`), and setting the `Indy` define (and then setting it again to use `Indy10` instead) allowed it to compile but didn't change any of the behavior. I'm going to look more into this later today.

Also, make sure that the `VersionInfoLocation` entry is only the URL (without the filename); the filename itself goes in the `VersionInfoFileName` property. If you put it in the URL, it gets repeated (as in `http://localhost/Remote/ProjectVersions_http.iniProjectVersions_http.ini`, and will fail anyway. (I found this while tracing through the debugger trying to solve the issue.)

Finally...

The solution is slightly (but not drastically) complicated. Here's what I did:

Copy `JvProgramVersionCheck.pas` to the demo folder. (It needs to be recompiled because of the next step.)

Go to Project->Options->Directories and Conditionals, and add the following line to the `DEFINES` entry:

```
USE_3RDPARTY_INDY10;USE_THIRDPARTY_INDY;
```

Delete the `JvProgramVersionHTTPLocation` component from the demo form.

Add a new `private` section to the form declaration:

```
private
  HTTPLocation: TJvProgramVersionHTTPLocationIndy;
```

In the `FormCreate` event, add the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  RemoteFileURL = 'http://localhost/';
  RemoteFileName = 'ProjectVersions_http.ini';
begin
  HTTPLocation := TJvProgramVersionHTTPLocationIndy.Create(Self); // Self means we don't free
  HTTPLocation.VersionInfoLocationPathList.Add(RemoteFileURL);
  HTTPLocation.VersionInfoFileName := RemoteFileName;
  ProgramVersionCheck.LocationHTTP := HTTPLocation;
  ProgramVersionCheck.LocationType := pvltHTTP;
  VersionCheck;  // This line is already there
end;
```

In the `ProgramVersionCheck` component properties, expand the `VersionInfoFileOptions` property, and change the `FileFormat` from `hffXML` to `hffIni`.

Delete or rename the `versioninfolocal.ini` from the demo's folder. (If you've run the app once, it stores the http location info, and the changes above are overwritten. This took a while to track down.)

Make sure your local http server is running, and the `ProjectVersions_http.ini` file is in the web root folder. You should then be able to run the demo. Once the form appears, click on the `Edit History` button to see the information retrieved from the remote version info file. You'll also have a new copy of the `versioninfolocal.ini` that has the saved configuration info you entered above.

Comment: I've added http://127.0.0.1/ProjectVersions_http.ini to the VersionInfoLocation, changed TJVProgramVersionCheck.LocationType property to pvltHTTP but still it doesn't work. Please note that if I paste http://127.0.0.1/ProjectVersions_http.ini in the browser, I can download the ini file from it

Comment: It does not even try to contact the http server

Comment: Thank you Ken very much! With your suggested modification i works.

Comment: Only a small issue is that I've had to add the conditional defines to the unit JvProgramVersionCheck.pas, right under the {$I jvcl.inc}:
{$DEFINE USE_3RDPARTY_INDY}
{$DEFINE USE_3RDPARTY_INDY10} because adding it to Project->Options->Directories and Conditionals, didn't compile, producing an error: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TJvProgramVersionHTTPLocationIndy'. This is weird, but at least it works!